# Why .then method does not populating the productList array globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with node.js and express. The problem arises while working with the routes. I have created an array named productList which I want to populate with json objects but my code is not working. The first console.log statement successfully logs the array of json objects but the second console.log statement logs the empty array.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var productList = [] ;
  Products.find()
  .then(products => {
    products.forEach(product => {
    productList.push(product) ;
    console.log(productList) ; // First console.log
   })
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json({'error': "Something wrong happened !!"}));

  console.log(productList) ;  // Second console.log
  res.render("products", {productList}) ;
});
```

Here **Products** is the name of a Document that is created successfully. I think the problem is related with the scoping of productList array. I don't understand what's wrong going on here. Please help.

Comment: it does populate it, you just check it too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `productList` BEFORE is has been populated.  Asynchronous operations in Javascript like `Products.find()` are asynchronous and non-blocking.  That means they get started and then your code continues to run and some time LATER, the `.then()` handler is called.

So, the sequence of operations in your code is:

1. Declare `var productList = []`.
2. Call `Products.find()` which  just starts the operation
3. Execute second `console.log(productList) ;` which show the list as empty
4. Call `res.render("products", {productList}) ;`
5. Then, sometime later, the `.then()` handler for `Products.find()` gets called.

As you can see from that sequencing, you're trying to use `productList` with `res.render()` before it has any data in it.

The usual solution here is to put the `res.render()` INSIDE the `.then()` handler as that's the ONLY place in your code where you know the timing of when `productList` has been filled in properly like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Products.find().then(productList => {
      console.log(productList);
      res.render("products", {productList}) ;
  }).catch(err => res.status(400).json({'error': "Something wrong happened !!"}));
});
```

Note, it does not appear that you need to copy over `products` to a new `productList` variable any more so I removed that extra step.

FYI, your `.catch()` handler should probably send a 5xx status which is typically what one would use when there was a database error.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. it clear's all my doubts.

Comment: what if in some case I have to first populate the productList array and then pass it to my template. How would I do that ?

Comment: @Mohd.Shoaib - I don't understand.  That's exactly what the code in my answer does.  It gets `productList` and then passes it to the template.